# how to reverse the animation when clicking on same element

Tags: jquery, html, css

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#Wrapper').click(function (){ 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#Article_1').toggleClass('magictime perspectiveDown'); 
        }, 1000);
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#fold12').toggleClass('magictime perspectiveDown'); 
        }, 2000); 
        setTimeout(function(){ 
            $('#fold123').toggleClass('magictime perspectiveDown'); 
        }, 3000);
   }
});
```

I have this jQuery code which works fine. When I click on the wrapper the first time, it will fold on itself from top to bottom. What I want is for the same animation to repeat again when I click on wrapper but upwards, i.e. from bottom to top.

I am using https://github.com/miniMAC/magic

How do I do that? Suggestions improving animation are also appreciated.

Comment: please provide jsfiddle.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you will need to store a flag with the `#Wrapper` so you know which way round to call the animations, probably just in some `data()`. Then if the flag is set you need to reverse the order. You can simplify this a bit and avoid just copy-pasting everything by storing the elements in an array and looping through that to calculate timeouts and the animation order:

**UPDATE**

As Chirag hinted, you also need to use `perspectiveDownRetourn` so the fold up animation works. You need to apply this to the elements at the start, preferably in the HTML, before you apply `magictime`, so they do not fold up at the start. Then in the code, toggle both `perspectiveDown` *and* `perspectiveDownRetourn`:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){ 

    // add perspectiveDownRetourn before magictime to avoid perspectiveDownRetourn playing at the start
    var articles = $("#Article_1, #fold12, #fold123").addClass('perspectiveDownRetourn');
    window.setTimeout(function() { articles.addClass('magictime'); }, 100);

    $('#Wrapper').data('showing', false).click(function () {
        var $this = $(this);
        var flag = $this.data('showing')

        var elems = ["#Article_1", "#fold12", "#fold123"];
        // if showing, reverse the display order
        if(flag) {
            elems.reverse();
        }

        // reverse the flag
        $this.data('showing', !flag);

        // loop elements and toggle both the down and up animations
        for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
            setTimeout(function(){
                this.toggleClass('perspectiveDown perspectiveDownRetourn'); 
            }.bind($(elems[i]), flag), (i + 1) * 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/css/magic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<button id="Wrapper">Click Me</button>

<div id="Article_1" class="">Article 1</div>
<div id="fold12" class="">Fold 12</div>
<div id="fold123" class="">Fold 123</div>
```

**Based on your fiddle**, here is the full code working in place

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
 <HEAD>


  <TITLE>Two Column Layout</TITLE>
<script 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://minimamente.com/example/magic_animations/css/magic.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


  
  


                  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
                  <script src="dist/animatecss.min.js"></script>
<link href="css/hover.css" rel="stylesheet" media="all">


  <style type="text/css">
    SECTION#Wrapper {
                 
 float: left;
 width: 700px;
 height: 1400px;
 margin-top: 5px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 50px;
}

ARTICLE#Article_1 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #ADAAAA;
}

HEADER#Header_Article_1 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

SECTION#Section_Article_1 {
 width: 680px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #F8EBEB;
}

ARTICLE#Article_2 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #ADAAAA;
}

HEADER#Header_Article_2 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

SECTION#Section_Article_2 {
 width: 680px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #F8EBEB;
}


ARTICLE#Article_3 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #ADAAAA;
}

HEADER#Header_Article_3 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

SECTION#Section_Article_3 {
 width: 680px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #F8EBEB;
}



ARTICLE#Article_4 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 300px;
 background-color: #ADAAAA;
}

HEADER#Header_Article_4 {
 width: 730px;
 height: 60px;
 background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

SECTION#Section_Article_4 {
 width: 680px;
 height: 200px;
 margin-left: 20px;
 margin-right: 20px;
 margin-bottom: 20px;
 background-color: #F8EBEB;
}

    </style>

                     </HEAD>


 <BODY>
  

  
  


  <SECTION ID="Wrapper">



 <div id="fold123">
         <div id="fold12">

   <ARTICLE ID="Article_1">
    <HEADER ID="Header_Article_1">
     <H2>Article One Title</H2>
    </HEADER>

    <SECTION ID="Section_Article_1">
     <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
    </SECTION>

   </ARTICLE>

             
   <ARTICLE ID="Article_2">
    <HEADER ID="Header_Article_2">
     <H2>Article Two Title</H2>
    </HEADER>

    <SECTION ID="Section_Article_2">
     <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
    </SECTION>


                                                </ARTICLE>
                                   </div>
                                     
                   
   <ARTICLE ID="Article_3">
    <HEADER ID="Header_Article_3">
     <H2>Article Three Title</H2>
    </HEADER>

    <SECTION ID="Section_Article_3">
     <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
    </SECTION>

   </ARTICLE>
                                            </div>

                                               <ARTICLE ID="Article_4">
    <HEADER ID="Header_Article_4">
     <H2>Article Four Title</H2>
    </HEADER>

    <SECTION ID="Section_Article_4">
     <P>The contents of this section go here.</P>
    </SECTION>

   </ARTICLE>


                    

  </SECTION>

     <FOOTER>
        <P>Your footer content here</P>
            
     </FOOTER>

      <script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){ 

        // add magictime here to avoid perspectiveDownRetourn playing at the start
        var articles = $("#Article_1, #fold12, #fold123").addClass('perspectiveDownRetourn');
        window.setTimeout(function() { articles.addClass('magictime'); }, 100);

        $('#Wrapper').data('showing', false).click(function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var flag = $this.data('showing')

            var elems = ["#Article_1", "#fold12", "#fold123"];
            // if showing, reverse the display order
            if(flag) {
                elems.reverse();
            }

            // reverse the flag
            $this.data('showing', !flag);

            // loop elements and toggle both the down and up animations
            for(var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
                setTimeout(function(){
                    this.toggleClass('perspectiveDown perspectiveDownRetourn'); 
                }.bind($(elems[i]), flag), (i + 1) * 1000);
            }
        });
    });
        </script>
      
  </BODY>
</HTML>
```

Comment: its work on first click in wrapper element.but after animation completes.when i click wrapper element again second animation not work.can you use "magictime perspectiveUp" for second click?

Comment: thx rhumborl for your reply. ia m really sorry for taking your time. i dont have jsfiddle account else i will provide you my whole code.

Comment: no problem - btw you don't need an account to create a jsfiddle - just add your code and press Save, then copy the page URL

Comment: thank you Rhumbori for such a valuable time given.this code works really fine without your help its not possible.Thank you very much again.